# malformed token exception from azure provisioning service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I followed the exact steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-net-provision-device-to-hub to register the device.

I am getting "malformed token" exception.

Here is the code from above link

```cs
private const string SampleRegistrationId = "sample-individual-csharp";
private const string SampleTpmEndorsementKey = "****"; //Key from Azure portal
private const string OptionalDeviceId = "myCSharpDevice";
private const ProvisioningStatus OptionalProvisioningStatus = ProvisioningStatus.Enabled;


static async Task SetRegistrationDataAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting SetRegistrationData");

    Attestation attestation = new TpmAttestation(SampleTpmEndorsementKey);

    IndividualEnrollment individualEnrollment = new IndividualEnrollment(SampleRegistrationId, attestation);

    individualEnrollment.DeviceId = OptionalDeviceId;
    individualEnrollment.ProvisioningStatus = OptionalProvisioningStatus;

    Console.WriteLine("\nAdding new individualEnrollment...");
    var serviceClient = ProvisioningServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceConnectionString);

    IndividualEnrollment individualEnrollmentResult =
        await serviceClient.CreateOrUpdateIndividualEnrollmentAsync(individualEnrollment).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Console.WriteLine("\nIndividualEnrollment created with success.");
    Console.WriteLine(individualEnrollmentResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used the connection string in incorrect format.Please note that do not contain ";" at the end of the connection string.
Maybe copying the connection string from Azure Portal is a good way to avoid to use the incorrect connection string.
[image]
If the error still exists, please feel free and let me know.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was connection string issue.

Comment: One quick question, The enrolled device is not mapped to any IoT. How can I do it from code? Like I want to read some configurations and set the IoTHub. I assume "Static configuration via the enrollment list" is the option but do not see enough articles.

Comment: I have posted the question here. Kindly help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265386/how-do-i-map-iothub-in-device-provisioning-service-enrollment-list